# Executable built with VS2010 does not find DLLs in System32

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

I recently built a project on VisualStudio. I got an executable in the bin folder and I put all the dependencies x64 DLL in `C:\Windows\System32` and all the x32 DLL in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

When I execute my executable, I get an error message `This program can't start because foo.dll is missing from your computer`.

I tried to get the dependencies with `ldd.exe` on Cygwin, but I don't see any references to `foo.dll`. I also tried to execute from PowerShell `Start-Process -PassThru sample.exe`, but I still get the same error message.

Where does Windows executables look for DLLs?

I've read that a Windows executable will look for its dependencies in a certain order:

- In the local folder
- In System32
- In the %PATH%

I also read that I may need to use `regsvr32.exe` to register my DLL if it is located into System32.

What is the actual reality of this story?

Comment: Is foo.dll the actual name of the DLL?  If not, please provide the actual name, as it may conflict with a well-known DLL.  Is the DLL part of your solution or is it third-party code?  Are you running the 64-bit version of the program or the 32-bit version?  What version of Windows are you running?  Why not put the DLLs in the same directory as the executable?  Is the DLL a COM server?

Comment: Are you sure that, when you copied the files to the system directories, that they actually ended up there and not in some redirected location?  Do you get different results if you try to run the program from Visual Studio or from a standard command prompt rather than cygwin?

Comment: Yes I am quite sure I put the 32-bits DLL into SysWOW64 and 64-bit DLL into System32. Can I provide you the DLL name (mkf3412.dll) but it will not help you since it is developed by some colleagues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can simply add the DLL files to the bin folder as well.

Comment: Yes this is a solution, but according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.100).aspx) information, an executable should also look on `System32`.